Powershell following rotation of log file
I know that is not a good idea runs a script for ever but, I need to continuously tail a log file, for some days, to get the evidence of some errors.
Problem is that this log file rotates multiple times during the day and I don't know how to follow it with powershell...
I'm stuck here:
$SRV = hostname
$FPath = "C:\Logs"
$LastFile = ( Get-Item "$FPath\*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Module"} | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 ).FullName
$LastActiveFile = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $LastFile).Hash
$ScriptPath = "E:\Scripts\ReInvite"
$CredPath = "$ScriptPath\Creds"
$logFile = "$ScriptPath\Logs\EventsReinvites.txt"

$CallEvent = "(^[\s\S]{0,21})(.*?)(CALLID:(.*?)@10)" 

While ( (Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path $(( Get-Item "$FPath\*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Module.log"} | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 ).FullName)).Hash -eq $LastActiveFile ) {
    Get-Content "$LastFile" -Tail 1 -Wait | foreach {
        if ( $_ -match "REINVITE" ) {
            $SipEvent = [regex]::match($_, $CallEvent).Groups[1,4].Value
            $SipEvent | Out-File -Append $logFile
            $Subject = "RMOD -> REINVITE event triggered..."
            $MSG = "Evento 'REINVITE' ricevuto su $SRV:"
            $MSG1 = "$SipEvent"
            $MSG2 = " "
            $MSG3 = "Script Path:   \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\$($ScriptPath.replace(':', '$')) "
            $MSG4 = " "
            $body = "$MSG" + "`n`n" + "$MSG1" + "`n" + "$MSG2" + "`n`n`n" + "$MSG3" + "`n" + "$MSG4"
            Send-MailMessage -Subject $Subject -Body $body @MailArgs | Out-File "$LogDir\MailLogs.txt"
        }
    }
}

Script do the job but, as soon as log rotates, an error occour:
Get-Content : Il file 'C:\Logs\Module.2024-07-09T07-28-27-355.1.log' non è stato trovato.
In riga:1 car:1
+ Get-Content "C:\Logs\Module.2024-07-09T07-28-27-355.1.log
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Logs\Module...28-27-355.1.log:String) [Get-Content], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

and script exits...
Please, help me! Roberto

"an error occour" - can you add the  full error message? (edit your post rather than put it in a comment).

@mclayton, FileNotFoundException

$LastFile is declared first and never updated. It can be declared in the head of while, but the command there is a little different. Why? Or u redeclare it at the end of the while body

@Dom, $LastFile never change its name, when the application rotate it, also gzip it and, as a result, file's extension and "previous" file's name changes, while the new one has the same name of $LastFile variable value. That's why I've tried to match the hash of file but, I think, any operations inside the while loop are useless if file changes on disk...

I think that the only solution possible is another scheduled script, that checks if the "first" script is running, but, I might be wrong!

So its overwritten?

@Dom, No, isn't overwritten: before rotation it's name is "xxx.log", after rotation become "xxx.log.gz" and soon after a new "xxx.log" is created

what if u put the whole "Get-Content "$LastFile" -Tail 1 -Wait | foreach {..." block into a try{}block and follow it up with a catch{ } where u redetermine $lastfile and run a foreach-object loop on that?

@Dom, I don't know try&catch block, I need to learn it!

A file with name 'Module.2024-07-09T07-28-27-355.1.log' will never match Module.log... Also your While loop condition makes it process the file only if it has NOT been updated

Everybody: If you are also working on this case and will present a probable answer soon, please give me a warning, cause I will put the time in now.  @Theo thats indeed true and is likely to be part of the problem, thank you!.

@Theo, forgive me Theo, I've changed the name of log file for posting here, I didn't realise about wrong match!  I'll correct it.

I wrote two scripts; first rollingLogCreator.ps1 to simulate the behavior of creating log files making entries, than changing their names (making an archive out of them) and creating the next log file with a different name:
param($interval=1,$intervalRotations=10,$totalUpdateLoops=30)
$ScriptPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$pathtoLogs=$ScriptPath +"\logs"
if(-not(test-path -path $pathtoLogs)){write-host "not $ScriptPath";New-Item -Path $ScriptPath -Name "logs" -ItemType Directory}
$FileFriendlyDate= (Get-Date -Format FileDateTime).toString()
$oldpath=$scriptpath+"\logs\Module"+ $FileFriendlyDate+".log"
start-transcript -path $oldpath
for($i=0;$i -le $totalUpdateLoops; $i++){
    "$((Get-Date -Format FileDateTime).toString()) $making porgress with giving update for the $iTh time"
    if(($i % 6) -eq 0){write-host "inportant reinvite event no $i"}
    start-sleep $interval
    if((($i % $intervalRotations) -eq 0) -and ($i -gt 0)){
        stop-transcript
        Rename-Item -Path $oldpath -NewName "ModuleZip$FileFriendlyDate.txt"
        $FileFriendlyDate= (Get-Date -Format FileDateTime).toString()
        $newpath=$scriptpath+"\logs\Module"+ $FileFriendlyDate+".log"
        start-transcript -path $oldpath
    }
}

And secondly rollingLogFollower.ps1 to observe the newest file in the given directory and react to the keyword "REINVITE":
  $LastFile = ( Get-ChildItem "$FPath\*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Module*.log"} | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 ).FullName
     
  Get-Content $LastFile -Wait -Last 0 |
  where-Object { $_ -match 'REINVITE' } |
  ForEach-Object {write-host "match"}

I was shocked by the simplicity of it, but it works: When the name of the log is changing "Get-Content -wait" seems to realise it on its own and update $lastfile. The only problem i ran into was starting the follower before starting the creator at the beginning. Then it was like the follower was already asleep not realising new files been created / updates are made. but after stopping it with cntrl+c and starting it over found the track and once it did i could keep it running and wait as long as i want to start the creator again and generate more logs. It wont loose track once its on to it, like a bloodhound.Please try for your self: You can adjust the parameter of your tests: $interval sets the time between each log entry,$intervalRotations is the number of entries till the script changes to the next logfile and $totalUpdateLoops will set total number of loops for your test. u can overload the default values declared at the beginning in "param()" by calling the script (drag & drop it into your powershell window) and append your numbers at the end so it looks like this eg:  "path\to\this\script\rollingLogCreator.ps1 2 4 80" After starting the creator start the follower in a different window. Once comfortable with this you can change the path of the follower to the real path.
